# Are the output voltages of each station correct? | Overflow error message when I add feedback

Tags: pid-controller, pspice

I'm building a PID controller with *PSpice For TI2020* and using operational amplifiers.
There is a `VPWL_FILE` that outputs 0V for the first second, then 2V thereafter. My controller should react to this "step function" and do what it is supposed to do.
The resulting voltages at the respective output of the individual stations (P, I, D, summing and inverter) look good in my opinion. The gains of the P, I and D components are 1 for test reasons.

I put in a differential amplifier last night to have a way of coupling the circuit's output to the input. If I just clamped the output between the source and the first op amp, the source just pushes the voltage straight to the output. Hence the idea of ​​using a differential amplifier. I connect the source (V9) to one input of the differential amplifier and the output of the controller circuit to the other. I would then connect the output of the differential amplifier to the input of the circuit. On the one hand there is an error message (`overflow, multiply`) and on the other hand I can't imagine that the results are correct.

**My question to you is: Do the curves look appropriate to you?**
To be more precise: Is it possible that when the step function is still at 0V, the integrator is already outputting -5V? Doesn't that spoil the overall result?

**My second question is: What can I do about the crashing simulation?**

Source, P, I, D, Summierer, Inverter

[image]

Schematic

[image: Schematic]

#### my plan to be able to have a feedback loop

[image]

Comment: Just a comment. Schematic would be more clear if using "labels" ... Try as this ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp4uA.png

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a bad connection: -

[image]

[image]

I'm not saying this is definitely THE problem of course.

Comment: Hello Andy, yes, I quickly pulled the wires to take a screenshot of my plan. I had previously disconnected the differential amplifier to get it simulated, and to be able to showyou the graph. Before (yesterday), everything was connected correctly, and it still didn't work. Um, how do you say this in English: You have found a "wrong" error.  It was stupid of me not to pay attention.

Comment: Aha that's what engineering is absolutely all about - attention to detail; one thing out of place and it all goes belly up. Never mind.

Comment: @Daniel the saying would be `this error is a red herring` ... `red herring` means `distraction from the real problem`